# Calculate median sales price with using 3 variables Tableau 10

Tags: tableau-api, median, calculation

I would like calculate the median sales price and the median rental price for an apartment in NYC in each of the 5 boroughs, Brooklyn, Bronx Manhattan, Queens and Staten Island. In Tableau the sales and and rentals are groups of ListPrice -- Variables ListPrice is NUMBER(decimal) Type (includes Sales & Rentals, Borough

Any help is appreciated

I tried using Tableau's table calculation feature but that did not work, I tried

```
WINDOW_MEDIAN(SUM([ListPrice])-1, -1)  

ERROR: WINDOW_MEDIAN is being called with (float, integer), did mean 
(float,integer,integer)
```

**Data**

```
Type             Borough       ListPrice
RentalType1      Manhattan       $5,000
RentalType2      Bronx           $3,000
RentalType2      Brooklyn        $3,000
SalesType2       Manhattan       $900,000
SalesType1       Brooklyn        $100,000
SalesType1       Bronx           $500,000
SalesType2       Queens          $800,000
SalesType2       Staten Island   $400,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table calculations takes 3 arguments, Expression, First row of the partition and last row of the partition. In your formula you haven't given last row of the partition.

Run the function for `type` in each Borough and calculate for each `Borough`.

So your formula would be:

```
WINDOW_MEDIAN(SUM(INT([List Price])),FIRST(),LAST())
```

[image]

are you looking to get values below:

Here calculation2 is median value

[image]